# Matrix visual show the total value but still limit the dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a matrix based on numbers of leavers and joiners. To calculate the closing balance of the month I give the value of a joiner **1** and the value of a leaver **-1**. I then sum up all the values before the closing balance date to get the closing balance of people.

**Example**

```
Name  │ Join/Leave │ date
──────┼────────────┼───────────
Mary  │  1         │ 2010-01-12
Mary  │ -1         │ 2016-06-17
Mark  │  1         │ 2019-02-14
Sammy │  1         │ 2015-12-20
```

Would mean my balance for 01-01-2019 is 1 but in February would be 2.

I want to show a total in the matrix but when I do it shows all the dates. My date dimension is not linked to my salesperson table.
Is there a way to show the months after today's date as blank but still show the total?

[image: This image] shows how the matrix now looks but I want October through to December 2019 to be blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a column in your query designer with the following M formula:

```
= if [YourDateColumn] <= Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()) then true else false
```

Now simply add your matrix with the month and value field. Then drag and drop the created column into to filter of the matrix and set the filter to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this blog post from SQLBI for a number of approaches](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/hiding-future-dates-for-calculations-in-dax/).

To sum up you have to main options, adding a new flag to your date table to allow you to filter out future dates or handling it dynamically in your measure to blank out values when the date is in the future.

Comment: Thanks, the issue with blanking out the future is that in the total column it becomes blank. Whereas I would want the total column to have a value.